How to find the minimum of a sum of values based on a distinct value?
Using the table below, I've been trying to figure out how I can find the smallest purchase amount based on a unique ID.
ID  |  UNITS_BOUGHT  |  UNIT_PRICE
----------------------------------
 1  |       1        |    10.99
 1  |       3        |    3.49
 1  |       2        |    4.99
 2  |       1        |    124.99
 2  |       1        |    4.99
 3  |       5        |    9.99
 3  |       3        |    4.99

What I need to do is get the total number of distinct IDs first, then find the smallest purchase amount amongst the distinct IDs. The purchase amount is found by taking UNITS_BOUGHT, then multiplying it by UNIT_PRICE, then summing the values for each ID. So, in this case, the total distinct IDs would 3, and the smallest purchase amount would be 31.44, the amount for ID 1.
IDs  |  MIN_PURCHASE
--------------------
 3   |     31.44

What I haven't been able to figure is how to display that smallest purchase amount. This is the current code I have:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS 'IDs',
ROUND(MIN(SUM(UNITS_BOUGHT * UNIT_PRICE) = (
    SELECT UNITS_BOUGHT * UNIT_PRICE
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY ID
)), 2) AS 'MIN_PURCHASE'
FROM TABLE;

The code above does provide an "invalid use of group function error", and I'm not entirely sure as to why that is.

@easleyfixed This was adapted from a university assignment, where the ID field was called something else. I didn't think that part was too important, as I just need help figuring out how to find the min.

@easleyfixed The id might be something like a OrderID or PurchaseID. And this data is representing multiple items bought in different quantities belongign to the same order. And the query is something like: "Get the number of distinct items in the Purchase with the lowes sum"

You might wanna use a CTE.
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID, SUM(UNITS_BOUGHT * UNIT_PRICE) AS TotalPurchase
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM YourTableName) AS IDs,
    ROUND(MIN(TotalPurchase), 2) AS MIN_PURCHASE
FROM CTE


You might wanna explain your code ...

Thank you. I had to read up a bit on what CTEs were, but this definitely did the trick for me.

the deleted answer does this much simpler (just needs the count of ids to use a subquery like this does)

if you are going to the bother of using a cte, why not go ahead and get the id count from that?  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS IDs, ...


SELECT MIN(SUM(UNITS_BOUGHT * UNIT_PRICE))
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID;


This doesn't really help me. Are you suggesting I reformat some code, or are you attempting to provide a solution? I'm still getting an "invalid use of group function" error.

SELECT MIN(a.amt) FROM (SELECT ID,SUM(UNITS_BOUGHT * UNIT_PRICE) as amt FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID) as a GROUP BY a.ID;
